# Changing resharper settings to suit mspec coding

Tags: resharper, mspec

When I create a new test like the following:

It should_get_something = () => foo();

When I hit the semi-colon resharper sticks private on the front of the delegate:

Private It should_get_something = () => foo();

I then have to remove it.

Can I tell resharper not to do this? I tried adding a rule to the naming style dialog selecting Machine.Specifications.It and unchecking Private but this had no effect.

Answer (score 3):

In general I recommend to set up ReSharper like Aaron has suggested [here](http://codebetter.com/blogs/aaron.jensen/archive/2008/10/19/getting-resharper-and-vs-to-play-nice-with-mspec.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Not strictly what you're asking about, but you should a look at [this](http://www.aspiringcraftsman.com/2010/02/resharper-naming-style-for-machine-specifications/) too.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can stop Resharper forcing you to use explicit private modifier. Just untick "use explicit private modifier" here:
Resharper - Options - Languages - C# - Other - Modifier